# How is response delivered if TCP load balancer / proxy terminates the connection?

Tags: tcp, load-balancing

It seems that (some) TCP load balancers would terminate the connection from client before sending the request to the backend server. I'm wondering what does the "terminates" mean. If it means closing the connection then how would the response be sent back to the client? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it means closing the connection ...

No it doesn't. Terminating in this context means that the endpoint of the TCP connection from the client is the load balancer. The load balancer then creates a different connection between load balancer and server to transfer the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If possible, could you provide more info on how the termination is done and how it's different than a passthrough load balancer?

Comment: @LaserTag: *"... more info on how the termination is done ..."* - I don't know what you expect as more information. There is nothing special to a load balancer here, just normal TCP. *"....  passthrough load balancer ..."* - there is no difference at the TCP level. *passthrough* usually refers to the aspect that TLS (encryption) is passed through, but the TCP is still terminated. This is more to distinguish from HTTPS load balancers which commonly terminate the TLS too.